# How to insert data in MySQL without refreshing the page, using AJAX and LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to insert a row in the db, without refreshing the page, using LARAVEL and AJAX, but when, I click the submit button,I receive the following error in the browser console response:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'writer_id2' cannot be null.
```

I guess, that the input data has not been submitted and the values are null, but then how do I receive the response/input data in the controller and insert it in the db at the same time?

**Route:**

```
Route::post('writers', ['as'=>'add-writer' ,'uses'=> 'HomeController@addWriter'])->name('add-writer');
```

**Controller:**

```
 public function addWriter(){
  $i = new Input();
  $dm=  new DataModel();
  $data= response()->json(['data'=>$i::all()]);
  $encode = json_encode($data);
  $decode = json_decode($encode,true);
  $decoded = [];
  $decodedNeeded = [];
  $inc = 0;
  $i2 = 0;




  foreach ($decode as $k=>$v){
      $inc++;
      $decoded[$inc] = $v;

  }
  foreach($decoded[2] as $k3 =>$v3){
      $i2++;
       $decodedNeeded[$i2] = $v3;
  }

  $this->insertUser = $decodedNeeded;



 $dm->addWriterMethod($decodedNeeded[1]['writer_id2'],$decodedNeeded[1]['status'],$decodedNeeded[1]['writer-skills']);
```

**AJAX**

```
 $('#add-writer-btn').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
     var id = $('input[name=writer_id2]').val();
     var status = $("input[name=status]").val();
     var skills = $('textarea').val();



     var form2 = $(this);
     var url2 = form2.attr('action');

     $.ajax({
         headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
         method: "POST",
         ContentType: 'application/json',
         url: url2,
         dataType: 'json',

         data: {

             'id': id,
             'status': status,
             'skills': skills

         },

         success: function (data) {
           alert('Added successfully!');
         }


     });



 });
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="add-writer">
               <b>Add writer</b>

                       <form action="{{url('add-writer')}}" method="POST">    
                  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">

             Writer_id2 <input type="number" id="writer-id-2" name="writer_id2">
                  <br>
               Open to suggestions   <input type="radio" value="Open to suggestions"  name="status">
                  <br>
                 Searching for orders  <input type="radio" value="Searching for orders"  name="status">

                  <br><br>
                  Writer skills <textarea   name="writer-skills"></textarea>



                  <input type="submit" value="Add" id="add-writer-btn" >

                       </form>

          </div>
```

Comment: arrays in php start at index 0, could it be that you want `$decodedNeeded[0]` ?

Comment: @FrankConry the `$inc++;` appears to start the data at index `1`. I agree it doesn't seem to be the ideal approach.

Comment: why are you encoding then decoding? Can you log or print the variable `$decodeNeeded` ? Whats its value?

Comment: I know, that they start at index 0, but when I remove   e.preventDefault() in ajax, I receive the response and I got the response `array(1) { [1]=> array(4) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "fRRUu4OlHiGloOHrW47CIDc883rKDliqPJ4Ox0ud" ["writer_id2"]=> string(5) "53252" ["status"]=> string(20) "Searching for orders" ["writer-skills"]=> string(6) "tretre" } } ` , but it redirects me, which is not the desired result in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems it works - but redirects - when you don't use ajax, but it does not work when you use ajax.

That would seem logical: When you don't use ajax, you send 4 key-value pairs to the server:

- _token
- writer_id2
- status
- writer-skills

And when you use ajax, you only send 3 key-value pairs, of which only 1 has the correct key:

- id
- status
- skills

So at the very least you need to change the data you send when using ajax.

So this:

```
     data: {
         'id': id,
         'status': status,
         'skills': skills
     },
```

Should be:

```
     data: {
         'writer_id2': id,
         'status': status,
         'writer-skills': skills
     },
```

Now you have at least the data part sorted, but it could still fail due to a missing `_token` and if that is the case, you would need to add that one too.

However, strangely enough the error message you receive, suggests that the token is unnecessary, which probably indicates a configuration error.

To simply add everything without having to assign variables manually, I would recommend using this instead:

```
 data: $('form').serialize(),
```

Now you will receive the exact same data as with the "normal" / non-ajax post.

Apart from that, I would also recommend listening for the form submit event instead of the button click so that your javascript will also handle any submits that are caused for example by using the enter-key.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments...

1) If your are using id in html tags maybe you can use `$('#yourid').val()` to get data.

2) Controller en Laravel receive one parameter by default it's $request, so

```
public function addWriter(Request $request) {
```

3) If you are using 2. You can use `$request->all();` or `Input::get('writer_id2');` it's not necessary instance a new Input();

4) In ajax you can use `$('div#add-writer form').serialize()` to serialize values in data.

5) In the controller you can use

```
$dm->addWriterMethod($request->writer_id2,$request->status,$request->writer_skills);
```

6) Don't use "-" in vars, ids, names... use "_" eg. `writer_skills`

7) Delete all crazy foreach (Or leave if they are necesary)

Please try these and let me know how it works :)